# module import invalid syntax

Tags: python, import

so I saved a derivative power rule module as PowerRule.py in python 27.
when I try to import it This Is what happens:

```
>>> import PowerRule

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import PowerRule
  File "PowerRule.py", line 1
    Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

and I dont know how to fix it. can you help me please?

Comment: That means there is an error in `PowerRule.py` - you might want to post that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to erase that top bit that IDLE put in youre code that looks something like this

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

you don't need it in you're actual code

if you aren't familiar with IDLE take a look at [this](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/idle.html)